# Integral $\int_{A}f(x)\mu (dx)$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Calculate integral $\int_{A}f(x)\mu (dx)$, where $A = (90, 100],f(x) = x^2,  \mu =
∑_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}δ_{k}$. 
My idea : $\int\limits_{(90,100]}x^{2} \mu (dx)$ present as a sum of integrals : $\int\limits_{[90,91)\setminus \{ 90\}} x^{2} \mu (dx)+ \int\limits_{[91,100]}x^{2} \mu (dx)$. The first integral equals 0 , so we need to calculate $\int\limits_{[91,100]}x^{2} \mu (dx)$. Is it good idea ? How to calculate this integral ?

Comment: Do you know how to do it for one fixed $k$, for example for $\frac{1}{91} \delta_{91}$?

Comment: @JohnMa Maybe  I can not imagine this .

Comment: Do you know what is the definition of $\delta_k$?

Comment: Just to make sure that I understand your notation: $\delta_k$ is a point mass at $k$ (e.g. a measure on $\mathbb{R}$ that gives measure 1 to any set containing $k$, and zero otherwise), and $$\int_{A} f(x) \,\mu(\mathrm{d}x) \left( = \int_{A} f(x)\, \mathrm{d}\mu(x) ?\right) $$ is integration of $f$ against the measure $\mu$?

Comment: yes, that means what you wrote.

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Comment: Let's make it simpler. Evaluate $\int_{a} \delta_b d\mu$.

Comment: I found another way 

I found another way 
$\int_{A} f(x) \,\mu(\mathrm{d}x) = \int\limits_{(90,100]\setminus \{ 91,\ldots , 100\}} x^{2} \mu (dx)+ \int\limits_{\{91,\ldots, 100\}}x^{2} \mu (dx)$ . I know that $\mu(\mathbb{R}\setminus \{ ... \}) = 0$. So $\int_{A} f(x) mu(\mathrm{d}x) = \int\limits_{(90,100]\setminus \{ 91,\ldots , 100\}} x^{2} \mu (dx)+ \int\limits_{\{91,\ldots, 100\}}x^{2} \mu (dx)=91^2 *\mu(\{ 91\})+\ldots + 100^2 \cdot \mu(\{ 100 \})= \sum\limits_{k=91}^{100} k^{2} \cdot \frac{1}{k}= \sum\limits_{k=91}^{100} k$